# Java SprinBoot Security + Active Directory attributes

Tags: java, spring-security, active-directory

I am using Java + SpringBoot Security for autorization on my web app.
Bellow is working config and no claims)

My questions:

1. Can I use this way to connect to AD for to get from AD attrubutes of users (eg. sAMAccountName, mail)?
2. There is possible setting up aceess to page by the AD groups?

If i right understand AuthenticationManagerBuilder just connector to AD.

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home", "/logout/**","/logout-success","/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
        authBuilder
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
                .userSearchBase("OU=Active,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru")
                .groupSearchBase("OU=Groups,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru")
                .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://regions.office.ru:389")
                .managerDn("CN=ldap_user_ro,OU=Service,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru")
                .managerPassword("passw");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching all users of the domain by their attributes (displayName).

```
public class LdapSearch {
public List<String> getAllPersonNames() {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://regions.office.ru:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=ldap_user_ro,OU=Service,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

    DirContext ctx;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    } catch (NamingException | javax.naming.NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    NamingEnumeration results = null;
    try {
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        results = ctx.search("OU=Active,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru", "(objectclass=user)", controls);

        while (results.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
            Attribute attr = attributes.get("displayName");
            String cn = attr.get().toString();
            list.add(cn);
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NamingException | javax.naming.NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (results != null) {
            try {
                results.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        if (ctx != null) {
            try {
                ctx.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
}
```